# Can't find Package and Tools buttons on the top part of the Android SDK Manager

Tags: android-sdk

I have Eclipse installed on Ubuntu with the Android SDK and latest JDK and JRE. I'm trying to manage add-on sites in the Android SDK Manager, but I can't find the two tabs for Packages and Tools as I normally do on my Windows PC with the same settings.

I also tried installing the ADT bndle, but still the same thing.

This is a screenshot of what I have:

[image]

This is what I'm expecting:

[image]

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, and any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the menu bar at the top of the screen, instead of inside the window? That's how Unity (the desktop environment in Ubuntu) works.

Comment: Sorry i dont quite understand you question...however i cant see the packages and tool tabs in any case

Comment: hi you are right! the question mark in your answer confused me a bit...i thought you were asking me (foolishly)..thank youuu